# Can I fix my lucky bamboo that has yellow stalks?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, lucky-bamboo

Is it possible to save my lucky bamboo plant? The stalk is yellow and starting to turn brown but the leaves are still green. I have cleaned the glass container it is in and placed it in indirect sun.

Comment: Are you growing it in soil or in water? They are often sold as cuttings in water, but they are not aquatic and for some reason prefer not being drowned (but admittedly are remarkably tolerant of it).

Answer (score 6):

A yellowing stalk (if it was originally green) means its going to die -you need to remove that stem asap so that any possible infection doesn't affect the other stems. In theory, the possible causes are: the plant was exposed to temperatures below 65 deg F; you've not been using purified water; the water level got a little low and the stem can no longer absorb water; its been exposed to direct sun; you've been over feeding or using incorrect feed.

My personal opinion and experience, though, is that when these plants are arranged in water in glass or clear containers, they seem very often to succumb to some sort of fungal infection, starting with the stem turning yellow, then shrivelling and developing black spots. They seem to do better growing in potting compost; lucky bamboo is actually Dracaena sanderiana, but in potting compost, it does need to be kept well supplied with water, but not left sitting in it in any outer tray or pot.

Comment: I only have one big stock that grew with about 8 leaves out of the top. the bottom is all roots

Comment: @renee - well that is unfortunate - in that case, you might as well wait and see if it finally does die. There's nothing you can do to help it at this stage, although personally, I'd at least try potting it up and keeping my fingers crossed.